# React setState for the const declared outside constructor

Tags: reactjs, state

I am new to React. I created a class component and there is a constructor.

I created this.state inside the constructor function.

On `componentDidMount` I called few functions and in those function create the const.

Can I use `this.setState({})` for those variables declared outside the constructor and created and called in the `componentDidMount()` function?

I got an error when I tried to use such variables in another function.

My code is the following:

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       web3: null,
       network: "",
       account: 0x0
  };
}

 componentDidMount = async () => {
  await this.loadWeb3();
};

 loadWeb3 = async () => {
  const web3 = await getWeb3();
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  this.setState({ account: accounts[0] });
 const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
this.setState({ networkId });
this.setState({ web3 });
console.log(web3); //
console.log(networkId); //got sucessfully console log over here
await this.setNetwork();
};

setNetwork = async () => {
  let networkName,
   that = this;

  await this.state.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, network) {
    switch (network) {
    case "main":
      networkName = "Main";
      break;
    case "morden":
      networkName = "Morden";
      break;
    case "ropsten":
      networkName = "Ropsten";
      break;
    case "private":
      networkName = "Ganache";
      break;
    default:
      networkName = this.state.networkId; //but got error over here "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
  }

  that.setState({
    network: networkName
  });

  console.log(this.state.network);
});
};
```

I got following error in setNetwork() default switch case

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because not all your code has arrow functions...

```
  await this.state.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, network) {
```

specifically this part is loosing the `this` of the function...

I would re-write that to be

```
await this.state.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType((err, network) => {
```

or use the `that` that you have defined upper in the function it's just that the `this` that you are trying to access on the switch is not the `this` that you had before anymore. Using arrow functions would fix that "context" issue for you

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro
So just to clarify if I did not declare a variable in this.state{} and declared as const in normal function like networkId in my case, I still can do this.setState({ networkId }); and use it as this.state.networkId; in any other function for the same component ?

Comment: @urjitonrails no. You can only use `setState()` for those keys defined in `this.state`. If it's not defined in `this.state`, i.e. ordinary variable, it won't cause a re-render.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-net.html#getnetworktype):

> Promise returns String:

You could use:

```
const network = await this.state.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();

setState({ network });
```